# La chanson québécoise « Le vieux cheval »

Tags: sens, québec, paroles-de-chanson

Je veux demander quelque chose sur une chanson canadienne, à savoir [le vieux cheval](http://leventdunord.bandcamp.com/track/le-vieux-cheval) du *Vent du Nord*. Ma question exige de la connaissance de toute la chanson.

> Le vieux cheval
>
> Mon cher voisin qui m'envoyait chercher
>   Un vieux cheval blanc qui est à l'extrémité
>
> Prends ton verre et moi la bouteille
>   Buvons un petit coup, affilons nos couteaux
>   Dépêchons-nous, d'aller y lever la peau
>
> Mon cher voisin tu t'es laissé aller
>   Combien d'hivers t'as été mal hiverné
>
> Tu m'entendras plus sacrer après toi
>   Personne n'aura aucun pouvoir sur toi
>
> Tu traîneras plus ton maître en hiver
>   Tous ces capucins et toutes ces valises.

J’ai presque compris le récit que l’on esquisse. Voici tout exprimé autrement :

- Au début, un garçon dit que son maître lui ordonne un garçon d’amener
  un cheval qui penche vers sa fin.
- Après, le maître dit au garçon qu’il faut tuer le cheval pour enlever
  sa peau.  **Je ne peux que deviner qu’est-ce qui le prochain morceau
  veut dire** : Peut-être le jeune serviteur reproche son maître de
  s’être débauché. Il dit que son maître a vécu beaucoup de mauvais
  hivers, qu’il les a survécus à peine, à suite de son mauvais
  comportement.
- À la fin, le maître se tourne vers son cheval, lui promettant un avenir paisible : Une fois qu’il sera mort, il pourra se reposer à l’écart des jurons de son maître et des boulots épuisants.

Pourriez-vous m’expliquer qu’est-ce que le serviteur dit à son maitre quant au cheval ?

Comment: Me revoilà. Je remercie chacun qui a pris la peine de donner des renseignements. Malheureusement, je tarderai à lire vos répliques car j’ai beaucoup d’autres choses à faire. Il est pensable que j’ai besoin de trois semaines pour finir tous les boulots dont je m’occupe maintenant. J’espère que cela ne vous dérange pas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pour moi, il n'y a qu'**un seul preneur de parole** pendant toute la chanson qui s'exprime en "je". Et trois protagonistes en tout, à savoir:

- Le maître du cheval, le propriétaire
- Le cheval
- Le voisin du maître du cheval, le "je" de la chanson

Le **premier couplet**, à savoir:

> Mon cher voisin qui m'envoyait chercher
>
> Un vieux cheval blanc qui est à l'extrémité

semble être la mise en situation générale de la chanson. Le sujet explique que son voisin, propriétaire d'un cheval blanc en bout de vie, l'envoie chercher.

Le **deuxième couplet**, à savoir:

> Prends ton verre et moi la bouteille
>
> Buvons un petit coup, affilons nos couteaux
>
> Dépêchons-nous, d'aller y lever la peau

est comme si le sujet répétait ce que son voisin lui a dit pour l'envoyer chercher le cheval et lui faire comprendre qu'il faut le tuer. On sous-entend un "Il m'a dit: "Prends ton verre....".

Le fait de boire avant de passer à l'action, et le fait d'insister sur "Dépêchons-nous", laisse à penser que le propriétaire du cheval veut se donner du courage pour l'abattre, et faire ça vite, avant de se raviser. Il semble tenir à son vieux compagnon.

Les **trois derniers couplets**, à savoir:

> Mon cher voisin tu t'es laissé aller
>
> Combien d'hivers t'as été mal hiverné
>
> Tu m'entendras plus sacrer après toi
>
> Personne n'aura aucun pouvoir sur toi
>
> Tu traîneras plus ton maître en hiver
>
> Tous ces capucins et toutes ces valises.

semblent être adressés au cheval, comme un "mea culpa" du chanteur avant de l'abattre. Il lui dit qu'il n'est pas très bien traité, et qu'il ne doit pas avoir peur ou lui en vouloir car il sera sans doute mieux mort.

Voici ce qui me met sur la piste que c'est bien au cheval qu'il s'adresse:

- Être hiverné (Mettre les bestiaux à l’abri dans les étables, pour l'hiver)
- Sacrer après toi (Donner un coup violent, en québécois)
- Ton maître (C'est le cheval qui a un maître, logiquement)

Voici comment je comprends cette chanson. ;)

Comment: C'est possible! Perso je crois que le cheval est déjà mort; il faut maintenant lui enlever cette peau. Tuer l'animal est facile, je ne pense pas que la chanson réfère à une sensibilité particulière. C'est dépecer un cheval entier qui constitue une sale job selon moi, et combien de temps ça peut-il prendre? Ça prend certainement une certaine dose de courage. Je pense que le cheval symbolisait sa pauvreté, et il ne traîneras plus ça avec lui ou il transportait des gens? Finalement je me demande aussi si les valises ne sont pas un produit du cuir obtenu; un changement de clientèle. +1

Answer (score 2):

Bon, je ne comprends pas pourquoi vous dites, "garçon" et "maître du garçon": on ne dit que "mon cher voisin" dans le chanson.

Le chanteur s'adresse a son cher voisin dès le début: "Mon cher voisin" est le vocatif. Et je crois que ce n'est jamais que le chanteur (et jamais le voisin, ni le cheval) qui parle.

Donc je trouve que la fin du chanson est ambiguë: le chanteur s’adresse-t-il maintenant au cheval au lieu qu'au voisin? Peut-être s’adresse-t-il encore au voisin, comme si le voisin était le cheval: et puisque le voisin a commandé la mort du cheval, maintenant il est ainsi/aussi l'heure pour le voisin de mourir.

Mais c'est une explication étrange, donc je n'en suis pas du tout certain.

Ou bien, quand il dit "Mon cher voisin tu t'es laissé aller", c'est au cheval qu'il s'adresse.

Comment: Moi aussi je ne comprends pas vraiment pourquoi j’ai pensé que ce garçon était le serviteur de son voisin. Je pense que j’avais besoin de sommeil :)

Comment: J'aime fort bien les chansons que vous avez choisi. J'apprends celui-ci pour le chanter à une des soirées de folk locales.

Answer (score 2):

I think that there's just one person (the sad, but realistic owner of the horse) talking to his old horse, who he refers to as "[son] cher voisin" (his dear neighbor) before putting him out of his misery.
The owner is trying to comfort and console his horse (I think that it's the horse that is the one who has let himself go and who has suffered through many hard winters) and is trying to justify his actions (to himself and to the horse) by pointing out to the horse that he won’t have to hear the owner cursing at him anymore and that he won't have to do hard work anymore.

Comment: If there is only one person, then in the first verse who is talking to whom? Who did the sending, and who was sent ('envoyait chercher")?

Comment: The only explanation for the first verse that would be consistent with the 'monologue' idea would be that the horse knew himself that "it was time to go " and had somehow let his owner know this. @ChrisW

Answer (score 2):

Je pense que les phrases

> Combien d'hivers t'as été mal hiverné

et

> Tu m'entendras plus sacrer après toi

ne doivent pas être comprises comme une suite logique. Quand on écoute la chanson, il y a le refrain entre les deux.

Il y a probablement un changement d'interlocuteur, voire de locuteur entre les couplets 2 et 3. Le narrateur principal parle à son voisin, puis le voisin s'adresse à son cheval.

Answer (score 1):

Le serviteur dit à son maitre que son comportement est la raison de ses malheur, de son "mauvais karma", notamment des hivers rudes et de la difficulté que le maitre a eu à les passer.

Answer (score 1):

Après moult relectures, au travers des trois derniers couplets commençant à "Mon cher voisin tu t'es laissé aller", le locuteur semble s'adresser au cheval à travers son voisin, comme s'il prenait sa place.

Il formule ainsi au voisin ce que le cheval est en droit de lui reprocher.

Le constat des misères équines passe par la parole humaine, il est fait par un tiers (le locuteur) qui ouvre le voisin à la sensibilité animale.

Tout en 'consolant' l'animal, il met le doigt sur la dureté du maître.